# Quora-like duplicated slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, ruby-on-rails-4

I've looked on SO for an answer to this question, but can't seem to find one.

Basically what I want to do is something like Quora's Url Structure, where if a profile has the name **Thomas Jefferson** it becomes **quora.com/thomas-jefferson**. If there is already a Thomas Jefferson on the site, then it would become **quora.com/thomas-jefferson-1**, and so on for x number of duplicates.

The FriendlyId gem has something sort of like this, but instead of incrementing they generate a SecureRandom string, which is kind of ugly.

I have a Rails model that looks like this so far:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :generate_slug

   def generate_slug do
      self.slug = loop do
         slug = to_slug(self.name)
         break slug unless Profile.exists?(slug: slug)
      end
   end

  def to_slug(name)
     self.transliterate.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9 ]/, ' ').strip.gsub(/[ ]+/, '-')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have an index on name column in profiles table.

You can fire a query to database to get all entries like the currently generated slug and get the max value. If database does not return anything use current slug else parse the integer part of the max slug and increment it with 1 to get a new slug.

```
def generate_slug
  slug = to_slug(self.name)
  max_slug = Profile.where("slug like '#{slug}-%'").max.try(:slug)
  self.slug = max_slug.present? ? slug : compute(slug, max_slug)
end

def compute(slug, max_slug)
  max_count = max_slug.gsub("#{slug}-", "").to_i + 1
  "#{slug}-#{max_count}"
end
```

*Untested code

Comment: This is susceptible to race conditions. You would need to wrap the SELECT query and INSERT query in a transaction to avoid this.

Comment: Or `generate_slug` can be called in a `before_save` callback which will automatically wrap it in a transaction.